# Can't find my sorting error here in PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to return part of a table that are between two dates but the entire table keeps getting returned. Not just the values between two dates. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong with my code below?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name, DateTime, FROM names");
$sorting = mysql_query("WHERE DateTime between '2012-12-12 17:09:00' AND '2012-12-12 17:06:00'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,$sorting))
{
$output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: how are the dates stored into the database? are they stored as string, datetime, etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple syntax errors, and really you should build the complete query before sending it to the mysql_query() function:

```
$query = "SELECT Name, DateTime FROM names";
$query .= " WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2012-12-12 17:06:00' AND '2012-12-12 17:09:00'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output[] = $row;
}

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have removed that. $output doesn't need to be defined beforehand, but if you want you can do a `$output = array();` before the while statement

Comment: I can't get this to work unless I define $query on one line like MRM has. hmmm

Comment: small detail I missed. The space in front of the " Where". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**[BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)** takes a min and max and in that order... You are passing it max and min

Comment: I tried switching the date around a few times but it didn't seem to make a difference. You are probably right, but there is something else wrong as well I think

Comment: There are bigger problems than that! Good spot though.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing 2 mysql queries into the function where you should be giving only 1.
The sorting variable is being discarded by php as it is only used to return a positive boolean, which is being used to signal the return type of the array.

Here it is re-written:

http://codepad.org/Y8EYaZrk

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Name, DateTime, FROM names WHERE DateTime between '2012-12-12 17:09:00' AND '2012-12-12 17:06:00'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$output[] = $row;
}
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: if you reverse the dates, I can get this to work, but it doesn't seem to work on two separate lines like dchrastil